# react date picker text box typing disable

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-date picker for my form. currently its works well. but problem is user can type text as a date. I need to typing disable in this textbox. When user focus date picker text box, calendar should be load. how I do this , this is my date picker textbox.

I am using below library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

```
   <DatePicker
            name="invoiceDate"
            className="form-control form-control-sm"
            type="text"
            size="sm"
            placeholder=""
            selected={date}
            value={values.setDate}
            onChange={datePickerChange}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
            readOnly
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom input for more details https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-input

````
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const ExampleCustomInput = forwardRef(
    ({ value, onClick }, ref) => (
      <button className="example-custom-input" onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
        {value}
      </button>
    ),
  );
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
    />
  );
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE SOLUTION:

in your return component use onInput that triggers validDateInput function

```
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";


export const AddEmployee = function (props) {
  const validDateInput = function (e) {
    e.target.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      onInput={(e) => validDateInput(e)}
      maxDate={new Date()}
      
    ></DatePicker>
  );
};

export default AddEmployee;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per their github this seems to work to disable user input

```
handleDateChangeRaw = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
render() {
  <DatePicker onChangeRaw={this.handleDateChangeRaw}/>
}
```